# how to check if i can read image from bundle using NSError?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i need to check if image was read.. i have this code:

```
[self setView];
-(void)setView{

for(int i = self.firstNumberOfImages; i <= self.lastNumberOfImages; i++)
{
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.%@",self.imageName,i,self.imageType]];
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
    [imgArray addObject:image];
}
......
}
```

and i want to add `NSError` to this code... how i can be sure that my images will be load without the app will crash? ( using `NSError` )
10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Below code

```
for(int i = self.firstNumberOfImages; i <= self.lastNumberOfImages; i++)
{
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString 
                     stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.%@",self.imageName,i,self.imageType]];
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
    @try{
        [imgArray addObject:image];
    }
    @catch(exception e)
     {
        NSLog(@"ERROR");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if `imageNamed:` returns `nil`.

```
for(int i = self.firstNumberOfImages; i <= self.lastNumberOfImages; i++)
{
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString 
                     stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.%@",self.imageName,i,self.imageType]];
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
    if (image) {
        [imgArray addObject:image];
    }
}
```

Comment: work's fine! 10x... but can i need to throw error using nserror

Comment: You can't "throw" an NSError. You return it as a reference from the function. Simply use the default initializer (check the documentation), set a fitting name and code and return it.